# CoffeeScript is not compiled in Play 2.1.0

Tags: coffeescript, playframework-2.1

I am trying my first steps with CoffeeScript in Play 2.1.0. I created a new application and placed my CoffeeScript file main.coffee in app/assets/javascripts/.

I expected that upon starting the play application (entering 'run' in the play console) my CoffeeScript would be compiled and the resulting main.js to be placed in the public/javascripts directory.

But no main.js gets created in that directory. Do I have to add some configuration somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [CoffeeScript doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/AssetsCoffeeScript):

> Note that managed resources are not copied directly into your application’s public folder, but maintained in a separate folder in target/scala-2.x.x/resources_managed.

And you have to access it through the `Assets` controller using reverse routing:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")">
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/AssetsCoffeeScript) describes:`CoffeeScript sources are compiled automatically during an assets command, or when you refresh any page in your browser while you are running in development mode.`

So, if you are not in `development mode`, you should use `assets` command to compile your CoffeeScript manually.

Before type in the `assets` command, make sure you have add the `sbt-coffeescript` plugin in your project by adding the following line in your `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
```

After enable CoffeeScript compilation by adding the previous line, go into your project's root dirctory and type in `sbt` command. In the `sbt` interact shell you can type in `assets` command and you will get some output like this:

```
$ assets
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 1 source(s)
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed May 30, 2015 9:43:29 PM
```

As you can see, CoffeeScript compile successfully.